# I got my insertSorted method to sort the random integers, but now my code isn't iterating 25 times as it should, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, sorting, iteration, compareto

I can't figure out why my code isn't iterating and printing 25 random numbers as it should be. My program should print 25 random numbers in ascending order. I am getting output without errors, but I'm printing anywhere between 4 and 7 numbers in ascending order. Any advice?

```
class ListNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   // package access members; SortedList can access these directly
   T data; // data for this node
   ListNode<T> nextNode; // reference to the next node in the list

   // constructor creates a ListNode that refers to object
   ListNode(T object) {
       this(object, null);
   }

   // constructor creates ListNode that refers to the specified
   // object and to the next ListNode
   ListNode(T object, ListNode<T> node) {
       data = object;
       nextNode = node;
   }

   // return reference to data in node
   T getData() {
       return data;
   }

   // return reference to next node in list
   ListNode<T> getNext() {
       return nextNode;
   }
} // end class ListNode<T>

// class SortedList definition
public class SortedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   private ListNode<T> firstNode;
   private ListNode<T> lastNode;
   private String name; // string like "list" used in printing

   // constructor creates empty SortedList with "list" as the name
   public SortedList() {
       this("list");
   }

   // constructor creates an empty SortedList with a name
   public SortedList(String listName) {
       name = listName;
       firstNode = lastNode = null;
   }

   // insert "insertItem" into the proper position within the sorted list
   public void insertSorted(T insertItem)
  {
      ListNode<T> currentNode = this.firstNode;
      ListNode<T> previousNode = null;

      // Finding the node that has the greater value
      while (currentNode != null) {

       // if node is greater than the inserted item, break. 
       if (currentNode.data.compareTo(insertItem) > 0) {
           break;
       }

       previousNode = currentNode;
       currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
      }

      // If the first nodes value is less than the inserted value, insert at beginning.
      if (previousNode == null) {
       insertAtFront(insertItem);
       return;
      }
      // If the end of list is reached then add at the end of the list.
      if (currentNode == null) {
       insertAtBack(insertItem);
       return;
      }
   }
   private void insert(T insertItem, ListNode<T> previousNode) {
       previousNode.nextNode = new ListNode(insertItem, previousNode.nextNode);
   }

   // insert item at front of SortedList
   private void insertAtFront(T insertItem) {
       if (isEmpty()) // firstNode and lastNode refer to same object
           firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
       else // firstNode refers to new node
           firstNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem, firstNode);
   }

   // insert item at end of SortedList
   private void insertAtBack(T insertItem) {
       if (isEmpty()) // firstNode and lastNode refer to same object
           firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
       else // lastNode's nextNode refers to new node
           lastNode = lastNode.nextNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
   }

   // remove first node from SortedList
   public T removeFromFront() throws EmptyListException {
       if (isEmpty()) // throw exception if SortedList is empty
           throw new EmptyListException(name);

       T removedItem = firstNode.data; // retrieve data being removed

       // update references firstNode and lastNode
       if (firstNode == lastNode)
           firstNode = lastNode = null;
       else
           firstNode = firstNode.nextNode;

       return removedItem; // return removed node data
   } // end method removeFromFront

   // remove last node from SortedList
   public T removeFromBack() throws EmptyListException {
       if (isEmpty()) // throw exception if SortedList is empty
           throw new EmptyListException(name);

       T removedItem = lastNode.data; // retrieve data being removed

       // update references firstNode and lastNode
       if (firstNode == lastNode)
           firstNode = lastNode = null;
       else // locate new last node
       {
           ListNode<T> current = firstNode;

           // loop while current node does not refer to lastNode
           while (current.nextNode != lastNode)
               current = current.nextNode;

           lastNode = current; // current is new lastNode
           current.nextNode = null;
       }

       return removedItem; // return removed node data
   }

   // determine whether list is empty
   public boolean isEmpty() {
       return firstNode == null; // return true if list is empty
   }

   // output list contents
   public void print() {
       if (isEmpty()) {
           System.out.printf("Empty %s%n", name);
           return;
       }

       System.out.printf("The %s is: ", name);
       ListNode<T> current = firstNode;

       // while not at end of list, output current node's data
       while (current != null) {
           System.out.printf("%s ", current.data);
           current = current.nextNode;
       }

       System.out.println();
   }
} // end class SortedList<T>
```

My ListTest class is coded as such

```
public class ListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SortedList<Integer> list = new SortedList<>();
        SecureRandom rNum = new SecureRandom();

        // insert 25 random (between 0 and 99 inclusive) integers into the list
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            // Your job is to modify insertSorted so that it creates a
            // sorted list one element at a time.
            list.insertSorted(rNum.nextInt(100));

        list.print();
    } // end class ListTest
}
```

Comment: Good code man, keep going :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget one step of inserting

```
        // insert "insertItem" into the proper position within the sorted list
        public void insertSorted(T insertItem) {
            ListNode<T> currentNode = this.firstNode;
            ListNode<T> previousNode = null;
            print();

            // Finding the node that has the greater value
            while (currentNode != null) {

                // if node is greater than the inserted item, break.
                if (currentNode.data.compareTo(insertItem) > 0) {
                    break;
                }

                previousNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
            }

            // If the first nodes value is less than the inserted value, insert at
            // beginning.
            if (previousNode == null) {
                insertAtFront(insertItem);
                return;
            }
            // If the end of list is reached then add at the end of the list.
            else if (currentNode == null) {
                insertAtBack(insertItem);
                return;
            } else {
                insertAtPreviousNode(previousNode, insertItem);
            }
            print();
        }

        // private void insert(T insertItem, ListNode<T> previousNode) {
        // previousNode.nextNode = new ListNode(insertItem, previousNode.nextNode);
        // }
        // insert item at front of SortedList
        private void insertAtPreviousNode(ListNode prev, T insertItem) {
            ListNode nNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
            nNode.nextNode = prev.nextNode;
            prev.nextNode = nNode;
        }

        // insert item at front of SortedList
        private void insertAtFront(T insertItem) {
            if (isEmpty()) // firstNode and lastNode refer to same object
                firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
            else // firstNode refers to new node
            {
                ListNode oldFirst = firstNode;
                firstNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
                firstNode.nextNode = oldFirst;
            }
        }

        // insert item at end of SortedList
        private void insertAtBack(T insertItem) {
            ListNode oldLast = lastNode;
            lastNode = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
            oldLast.nextNode = lastNode;
        }
```

, output

```
The list is: 3 8 9 11 13 16 23 25 29 35 37 43 46 48 49 60 67 68 71 75 78 81 82 92 93
```

Comment: This is the output for duplicate numbers: `The list is: 5 6 8 13 16 17 18 28 32 34 37 38 41 42 47 53 56 57 58 58 69 79 79 89 93`